# Installing ORDS (without APEX)

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-ords

I'm having difficulties getting ORDS 3.0.4.60.12.48 to work on a Tomcat 7.0.68 server. The database itself is Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

Whenever I try to access the ORDS page at `localhost:8080/ords`, I'm getting a 404 error. After enabling the  `debug.printDebugToScreen` property, the page is displaying the following:

**Debug Trace**

```
Could not find any dispatcher to handle request:
--Attributes--
apex.diagnostic.context = ...
ECID-Principal = ECIDPrincipal [ecid=DRfgpsk1Jpq7KZ67hEo6Dw..]
oracle.dbtools.http.ecid = ogil1RMV3372zbyEOpN1Rg..
oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services = Request Scope
--Attributes--
GET /ords/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
connection: keep-alive


org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@139aac67
```

**Stack Trace**

```
DispatcherNotFoundException [statusCode=404, reasons=[]]
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.choose(Dispatcher.java:86)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:96)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:153)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:89)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:59)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:67)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:73)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:89)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:62)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:69)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.locale.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:60)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:75)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.ecid.ECIDFilter.doFilter(ECIDFilter.java:35)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:49)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchableServices(HttpEndpointBase.java:156)
  at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:85)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Unfortunately, I didn't really find a whole lot of info online about this. A lot of it was checking APEX specific users which I'm not using. Of what I did find, I already checked and can confirm that I can log in as `ORDS_PUBLIC_USER` manually, and I've tried copying the `ojdbc.jar` files from my Oracle client to the Tomcat `lib` folder. However, the problem seems to persist.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Edit] So I tried reinstalling it with a fresh ORDS configuration and realized that my installation did not have an `apex_pu.xml` file in the `ords\conf\` directory. However, I'm still getting a similar error:

**Debug Trace**

```
 mapped request using: /* to: apex_pu

Could not find any dispatcher to handle request:
--Attributes--
apex.diagnostic.context = ...
ECID-Principal = ECIDPrincipal [ecid=wDuKj9PEUNnl3Oy8vwesDg..]
oracle.dbtools.http.ecid = xXACfwD3YDNtXCQUNuqIAw..
oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services = Request Scope
--Attributes--
GET /ords/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
connection: keep-alive


org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1405a57f

mapped request using: /* to: apex_pu

Could not find any dispatcher to handle request:
--Attributes--
apex.diagnostic.context = ...
ECID-Principal = ECIDPrincipal [ecid=wDuKj9PEUNnl3Oy8vwesDg..]
oracle.dbtools.http.ecid = xXACfwD3YDNtXCQUNuqIAw..
oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services = Request Scope
--Attributes--
GET /ords/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
connection: keep-alive


org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1405a57f
```

The stack trace is near identical to before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all a mistunderstanding on my part. I had assumed that `localhost:8080/ords` and `localhost:8080/ords/ordstest` should have returned some sort of metadata, but it doesn't look like that was the case.

After following the `getting-started` guide in the `examples` folder from ORDS to setting up an `ORDSTEST` schema and running

```
exec ords.enable_schema();
exec ords.enable_object(p_object => 'EMP');
commit;
```

in lieu of not wanting to download SQL Developer, I managed to get `http://localhost:8080/ords/ordstest/emp` to successfully return data.

Comment: yeah, you don't need SQL Developer, but if you already have it, you can install/admin/deploy restful services with it. we have pl/sql APIs for everything, as you saw on the schema and object enablement